# How to make custom comment fields required

Tags: functions, custom-field, comment-form

In wordpress theme i create a custom field with name `city` in comments form.
Its showing and save data well. But problem is that its save the value while its empty. Need Its show error when submit form with empty city field.

i add function for validations but not working.

**How to make city comment fields required??**

> **Function.php**  complete code for city comment field

```
// Add the fields to comment form
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'change_comment_form_defaults');
function change_comment_form_defaults( $default ) {
     $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
     $default[ 'fields' ][ 'email' ] .= '<p class="comment-form-author">' .
                                        '<label for="city">'. __('City') . '</label>
                                        <span class="required">*</span>
                                        <input id="city" name="city" size="30" type="text" /></p>';
return $default;
}

// validations
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'verify_comment_meta_data' );
function verify_comment_meta_data( $commentdata ) {
      if ( ! isset( $_POST['city'] ) )
         wp_die( __( 'Error: please fill the required field (city).' ) );
      return $commentdata;
}

// And save the comment meta
add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_comment_meta_data' );
function save_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ) {
      add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'city', $_POST[ 'city' ] );
}

// Retrieve and display comment meta
add_filter( 'get_comment_author_link', 'attach_city_to_author' );
function attach_city_to_author( $author ) {
       $city = get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'city', true );
       if ( $city )
            $author .= " ($city)";
       return $author;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add below code into your current theme's function.php

```
function custom_validate_city() {
    if( empty($_POST[ 'city' ])) // do you url validation here (I am not a regex expert)
        wp_die( __('Error: please enter a city') );
}

add_action('pre_comment_on_post', 'custom_validate_city');
```